# identify which is the polygon from latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, jquery, polygon, latitude-longitude, leaflet

I have a map drawn using leaflet.js. If I give longitude and latitude value as input 
Can I identify the polygon? Can I get a client side script for this?

Comment: you need to give lat and lng value for polygon shape.if you give one lat lng value it ll represnt the dot.while giveing the more lat lng it ll draw polygon.starting and ending lat lng should be same.

Comment: Yes, look up a geodetic point-in-polygon (PIP) algorithm.

Comment: I have a map drawn using some set of lat and lng values. But now I want to know the polygon id from one set of lat and lng value.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984699/latlong-falls-within-a-given-polygon-in-d3-leaflet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got an answer as follows :

//This is based on 'point in polygon algorithm'

```
function getPoint () {
     float x=-89.82421875;     //x and y represents the lat and lng values
     float y= 40.18307014852533;
    var a = boundaries;    //the coordinates used to draw the map
    for (i = 0; i < a.features.length; i++) {
        PointInPolygon(x,y, a.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0], i);
    }
};

function PointInPolygon(pointX, pointY, _vertices, number) {
        var j = _vertices.length - 1;
        var oddNodes = false;
        var polyX, polyY,polyXJ,polyYJ;

        for (var i = 0; i < _vertices.length; i++) {
            polyY = parseFloat(_vertices[i].toString().split(",")[1]);
            polyX = parseFloat(_vertices[i].toString().split(",")[0]);
            polyXJ = parseFloat(_vertices[j].toString().split(",")[0]);
            polyYJ = parseFloat(_vertices[j].toString().split(",")[1]);
            if (polyY < pointY && polyYJ >= pointY ||
                polyYJ < pointY && polyY >= pointY) {
                if (polyX +
                    (pointY - polyY) / (polyYJ - polyY) * (polyXJ - polyX) < pointX)  
                {  
                    oddNodes = !oddNodes;  
                }  
            }  
            j = i;
        }
        if (oddNodes == true) {
             map._layers[number+1].fire('click');             //fire the map click event
        } 
    }
```